# SSL Multiple Domain is possible?

Tags: ssl, server

I have a project to build website builder with custom domain in feature. I want all user can register their domain with the HTTPS, is possible?

Is there ssl provider with unlimeted domain or there is diffrent way?

Comment: LetsEncrypt allows unlimited domain, but I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve here. A single cert for multiple domains? A single box handling multiple domains, each with their own cert?

Comment: Can i do 1 domain for 1 cert in 1 VPS?

Comment: Sure, a VPS theoritically can have unlimited amount of sites hosted, each with their own domain and cert